# Different URLs used despite having same launchSettings.json in local enironment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an API website. Here is my *launchSettings.json*.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40682",
      "sslPort": 44360
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "TTRailtrax": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7184;http://localhost:5184",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this project, the URL used is *https://localhost:44360*.

But when I check out my code on a different computer and run the project, the URL is *https://localhost:7184*.

I the URL to be the same on all computers because this API is called from another website in the solution.

I can see the second URL is coming from the *TTRailtrax* profile, but I don't really understand what these profiles are, or why different computers seems to be choosing different ones. I have confirmed *launchSettings.json* is checked into source control and is the same on both computers.

**Update**

Here's what I've learned so far. The two profiles are created by default. One of them (*TTRailtrax*) will use the Kestral server. The other (*IIS Express*) will use IIS Express. I'm not sure why there are two servers or what are the considerations when choosing between them.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) shows a dropdown where you can select which profile is being used. I cannot find this anywhere on my system (Visual Studio 2022).

If I go into the project's settings and open the debug launch profiles UI, I can edit the *App URL* field. However, the *App SSL URL* field is disabled. (I am using SSL.)

I have not figured out why one of my computers is selecting one profile while the other computer selected the other profile.

Comment: These are called debug profiles. So you have 2 debug profiles (`IIS Express` and `TTRailtrax`.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar: I think I know that much. But I don't understand why I have two profiles. And I don't understand why one computer seems to be using one profile and the other computer is using another profile. The example in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) also has two profiles, so they appear to be created automatically.

Comment: What was the name of the project when it was created

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar: *TTRailtrax*

Comment: @JonathanWood You have two different profiles because one of them is hosted via IIS and the other is hosted via Kestrel. I believe both these profiles are created by default. However, if you're not using one of them, you should feel free to remove it

Comment: What do you have configured as your startup project(s)? The "Start" drop down will only include the launch profiles for the startup project(s). If there's no launchSettings file(s), it will only have the generic "Start" option. I don't think the startup projects follow you to other machines unless the user settings are shared. I'm not 100% sure on that but most of the time when I'm getting started on a project from VC, I have to set that up myself.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Thanks, that helped me solve one of the problems. I have multiple startup projects. (The main site and my API site.) If I just select one project, then it does show the IIS Express/TTRailtrax startup options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS Express profile is for developers who plan to host their app on IIS and want to emulate that environment locally as close as possible. The Kestrel profile is for those who don't want the IIS Express profile - because they do not plan to host using IIS, for example, or because they want their debugging experience to be quicker.

VS remembers which profile you last used to launch the app, so the fact that the version on one machine uses the Kestrel profile suggests that you must have selected that profile at some stage previously. Perhaps this selection was not  a deliberate choice on your part.

The dropdown is included as part of the Run button. You have two green arrows, one of them solid and the other outlined. The name of a selected launch profile appears next to the solid green arrow.

Comment: The Run button? Do you mean the button that says Start? That dropdown has no options for IIS Express or TTRailtrax for me. An image might help, but I don't see anything like that on my Start button. (P.S. I've found your website helpful a number of times, and your Razor Pages book is already in one of my Amazon lists.)

Comment: I see now it was because I had multiple startup projects. In that case, the IIS Express/Kestral options are not available anywhere.